# Facebook Graph API Limited User Data Set

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm a beginner with Facebook Graph API.

I have a Facebook application and I seem to be able to use the API via my HTTP client.

The problem I'm having is that the user data I'm receiving is very limited. I'm just getting two fields, name and id (here's an example with made-up data to show the JSON format:

```
{
  "name": "John Smith",
  "id": "238475638375462"
}
```

I know there are a lot more fields, so where are they? Is it possible that because my application isn't fully approved by Facebook yet that they're limiting my scope?

Here's the API endpoint documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the solution is quite simple. The details are buried in the API documentation. It's really just a matter of "choosing fields" as explained [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api).

If I want fields other than the default name and id, I must list them in the query string. Here's an example

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/238475638375462?fields=id,name,birthday,email&access_token=BIG_LONG_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Gives me:

```
{
  "id": "238475638375462",
  "name": "John Smith",
  "birthday": "10/10/1990",
  "email": "user@example.com"
}
```

Concerns about scoping are also quite valid here. I found the Facebook [Access Token Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/) useful to confirm my scopes and keep me headed in the right direction.